# Observer that runs when an order is attempted to be created in the Admin

Tags: event-observer, plugin, before-plugin

I need to create an observer or plugin or something else that will run when an order is attempted to be created through the admin. I added a custom attribute for customers (offline/online). If the attribute is set to offline then an order can not be created for the customer. Is there event that can be observed or is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Feel free to accept some answer if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a look to **vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create.php** file

You'll find some events there, such as `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before`, `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_item_before`, `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data`, etc...

Depending by which exact moment you need to run your validation you may choose one or another

Another approach: I believe you could use almost all generic order events during checkout in frontend, but just placing your **events.xml** file in **etc/adminhtml** folder in your module. This way they will run only in admin requests

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Plugin aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder. This plugin will execute on the click of Place Order before order generation on checkout Page.
Remember you need to overwrite two classes GuestPaymentInformationManagement
and PaymentInformationManagement.